# jenkins - git publisher error

Tags: git, jenkins

Git publisher in jenkins keeps failing and says "Please tell me who you are". I've tried running git config --global user.name and user.email however that dit not help

```
14:25:36  > git tag -l jenkins-jobname1 # timeout=10
14:25:36  > git tag -a -f -m Jenkins Build #101 jenkins-jobname-SUCCESS # timeout=10
14:25:36 ERROR: Failed to push merge to origin repository
14:25:36 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not apply tag jenkins-jobname-SUCCESS
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.tag(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1373)
14:25:36    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:274)
14:25:36    at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher.perform(GitPublisher.java:215)
14:25:36    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
14:25:36    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
14:25:36 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git tag -a -f -m Jenkins Build #101 jenkins--jobname-SUCCESS" returned status code 128:
14:25:36 stdout: 
14:25:36 stderr: 
14:25:36 *** Please tell me who you are.
14:25:36 
14:25:36 Run
14:25:36 
14:25:36   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
14:25:36   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
14:25:36 
14:25:36 to set your account's default identity.
14:25:36 Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
14:25:36 
14:25:36 fatal: empty ident name (for <jenkins@jenkins01.(none)>) not allowed
14:25:36 
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1799)
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1772)
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1768)
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1415)
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1427)
14:25:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.tag(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1371)
14:25:36    ... 11 more
14:25:36 Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
```

any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: did you run `git config` as jenkins user (or whatever user it's using)?  if it's using jenkins user: `sudo -u jenkins git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` (and then the same with user.name). this will create .gitconfig in that user's home.

Comment: yup I have but it didn't help

Comment: strange - just ran it again and it worked. thanks! Can you add it as a solution and I'll mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: glad to hear that! there it is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's using jenkins user:

```
sudo -u jenkins git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
sudo -u jenkins git config --global user.name "Your name"
```

this will create `.gitconfig` in that user's home.